# make two custom columns sortables

Tags: sort, columns

I have 2 custom columns, `typeconsole` and `console`:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', function( $columns ) { 
        $columns['typeconsole'] = 'typeconsole';
        $columns['console'] = 'console';
        return $columns;
});
```

This answer allows me to sort the first column:
[Make custom column sortable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293318/make-custom-column-sortable). When pressing the second column, the first one is ordered.

How do I make them work independently?

Comment: There is no sorting code in your question, can you edit it to include it? The original answer includes a `pre_get_posts` filter but yours does not

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using the add and populate the columns as well?