# Admin custom post ordering

Tags: custom-post-types, order, sort

I'm trying to order custom posts in admin page using an acf date/time value,

I've found a useful resource on [wpmunchies.com](https://wpmunchies.com/sortable-admin-columns-with-advanced-custom-fields-acf/)

I've made some changes, so my code is the following:

```
function convertDateFormat($dateString){
    $current_date_A = explode(" ",$dateString);
    $year = $current_date_A[2];
    $monthMap = [
        'Gennaio' => '01',
        'Febbraio' => '02',
        'Marzo' => '03',
        'Aprile' => '04',
        'Maggio' => '05',
        'Giugno' => '06',
        'Luglio' => '07',
        'Agosto' => '08',
        'Settembre' => '09',
        'Ottobre' => '10',
        'Novembre' => '11',
        'Dicembre' => '12'
    ];
    $month = $monthMap[$current_date_A[1]];
    $day = $current_date_A[0];
    $current_time = explode(".",$current_date_A[3]);
    $hour = $current_time[0];
    $minute = $current_time[1];
    $current_date_F = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute . ':00';
    return $current_date_F;
}
function my_page_columns($columns) {
  $columns = array(
      'cb'  => '<input type="checkbox" />',
      'title'   => 'Title',
      'dataora'     => 'Data',
  );
  return $columns;
}

function my_custom_columns($column) {
  global $post;
  if($column == 'dataora') {
    $curdata = convertDateFormat(get_field('data'));
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $curdata);
    if( empty( $date ) ) :
     echo 'No Date';
    else:
     echo $date->format('j F H.i');
    endif;
  }
}

add_action("manage_proiezione_posts_custom_column", "my_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-proiezione_columns", "my_page_columns");

function my_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
  $columns['dataora'] = 'dataora';
  return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-proiezione_sortable_columns", "my_column_register_sortable" );
```

This works with existing posts, but it doesn't with new posts, which are placed at the end of the list, regardless of the value of 'data'

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note the [`manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_post-post_type_posts_custom_column/) has a second parameter `$post_id` that you can use rather than `global $post`.

Comment: Taking a look at `pre_get_posts` action for the sorting query may be helpful. May need to make adjustments to the query so it sorts correctly. See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/293403/59678